# Check if the entity is new from the entity insert hook

Tags: hooks, 8, entities

I have a custom content type, when I create a new content of this type via the admin ui I want be redirect to the edit page of the new node (not to the view page by default)

So, from an alter form hook, it's not possible because I don't know yet the node ID of the future node. From `hook_entity_presave()` it's the same: I don't know yet the node ID of the future node. From `hook_entity_insert()` hook, I have the node ID, but I don't know how can I check the entity is just created.

From `hook_entity_insert()`, is it possible to know if the entity is just created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hook_entity_insert()` is invoked only when an entity is created, not updated. That is evident from the method invoking it, [`EntityStorageBase::doPostSave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AdoPostSave/8).

```
  // Allow code to run after saving.
  $entity->postSave($this, $update);
  $this->invokeHook($update ? 'update' : 'insert', $entity);
```

`hook_entity_update()` is invoked for an entity being updated; otherwise `hook_entity_insert()` is invoked.

See also the description for the `$update` parameter passed to `EntityStorageBase::doPostSave()`.

> **bool `$update`**: Specifies whether the entity is being updated or created.